# pip error code 1 when installing pyopenssl

Tags: python, pip

Hi I am trying to install pyopenssl so i can use scrapy. When i run the installation i get this error with pip. I also get the same error when trying to install scrapy...

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hy/76g5m82s4nx4b8f4m1tzdd9h0000gn/T/pip_build_joegavin/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/joegavin/.pip/pip.log
```

here is my pip list incase i'm missing something

```
apptools (4.2.1)
argcomplete (0.6.7)
astropy (0.3)
atom (0.3.7)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
beautifulsoup4 (4.3.1)
binstar (0.4.4)
biopython (1.63)
bitarray (0.8.1)
blaze (0.4.2)
blz (0.6.1)
bokeh (0.4.1)
boto (2.25.0)
casuarius (1.1)
cdecimal (2.3)
chaco (4.4.1)
colorama (0.2.7)
conda (3.4.2)
conda-build (1.3.1)
configobj (4.7.2)
cubes (0.10.2)
Cython (0.20.1)
DataShape (0.1.1)
distribute (0.7.3)
docutils (0.11)
enable (4.3.0)
enaml (0.9.1)
envisage (4.4.0)
Flask (0.10.1)
future (0.11.2)
gevent (1.0)
gevent-websocket (0.9.2)
gevent-zeromq (0.2.2)
greenlet (0.4.2)
grin (1.2.1)
h5py (2.2.1)
ipython (2.0.0)
itsdangerous (0.23)
jdcal (1.0)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
keyring (3.3)
kiwisolver (0.1.2)
llvmpy (0.12.3)
lxml (3.3.5)
MarkupSafe (0.18)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
mayavi (4.3.1)
MDP (3.3)
mock (1.0.1)
netCDF4 (1.0.8)
networkx (1.8.1)
nltk (2.0.4)
nose (1.3.0)
numba (0.12.1)
numexpr (2.3.1)
numpy (1.8.0)
openpyxl (2.0.2)
pandas (0.13.1)
patsy (0.2.1)
pep8 (1.4.6)
PIL (1.1.7)
pip (1.5.6)
ply (3.4)
psutil (1.2.1)
py (1.4.20)
PyAudio (0.2.7)
pycosat (0.6.0)
pycparser (2.10)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycurl (7.19.0)
PyExcelerate (0.6.1)
pyface (4.4.0)
pyflakes (0.7.3)
Pygments (1.6)
pyinstall (0.1.4)
PyInstaller (2.1)
pykit (0.2.0)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
PySAL (1.6.0)
pysam (0.6)
pytest (2.5.2)
python-dateutil (1.5)
pytz (2013b)
PyYAML (3.11)
pyzmq (2.2.0.1)
redis (2.9.1)
requests (2.2.1)
rope (0.9.4)
scikit-image (0.9.3)
scikit-learn (0.14.1)
scipy (0.13.3)
setuptools (5.1)
six (1.5.2)
Sphinx (1.2.1)
spyder (2.2.5)
SQLAlchemy (0.9.2)
statsmodels (0.5.0)
sympy (0.7.4.1)
tables (3.1.0)
tornado (3.2)
traits (4.4.0)
traitsui (4.4.0)
ujson (1.33)
virtualenv (1.11.5)
VTK (5.10.1)
Werkzeug (0.9.4)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
xlrd (0.9.2)
XlsxWriter (0.5.2)
xlwt (0.7.5)
```

I've tried updating setup tools, reinstalling pip. I'm on OSX can anybody help? Thanks

UPDATE :  Pastebin for pip.log : http://pastebin.com/MTNrR0n5

Comment: Update your question with the contents of `/Users/joegavin/.pip/pip.log`.

Comment: Do you have brew installed?

Comment: no I don't, should i install it and try again?

Comment: The error indicates a lack of openssl libraries for compiling the extension.

Comment: I tried to install it using easy install and it now comes up on the list but it still gives me this:

 Referenced from: /var/folders/hy/76g5m82s4nx4b8f4m1tzdd9h0000gn/T/easy_install-FpCQYt/cryptography-0.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_444d7397xa22f8491.so
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 1):

Error code 1 sometimes occurs due to lack of permissions. If you have an admin account, try prefacing your command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Python lacks `openssl` support?
You can find out:

```
python
>>> import socket
>>> hasattr(socket, 'ssl')
True
```

If `socket` doesn't have the `ssl` attribute, you don't have the needed capabilities.

AFAIK, `openssl` support must be selected for compilation of the Python interpreter and cannot be installed afterwards.